# Mongoose `ValidationError` in NestJS when `model.toObject()` shows the correct data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, nestjs

I am rewriting a legacy app in NestJS. They both connect to the same MongoDB server. I have my mongoose schemas setup to match the expected data in Mongo.

However, there appears to be some bad data in Mongo from a long time ago (this is a very old app). For some reason, mongoose throws a validation error when trying to save it with the new data structure.

### The Received Error

```
name: 'ValidationError',
message: 'Domain validation failed: contacts: Tried to set nested object field `contacts` to array ``',
stack: 'ValidationError: Domain validation failed: contacts: Tried to set nested object field `contacts` to array ``\n' +
  '    at model.Document.invalidate (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3165:32)\n' +
  '    at SingleNested.Subdocument.invalidate (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/subdocument.js:225:12)\n' +
  '    at _init (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:791:18)\n' +
  '    at init (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:738:5)\n' +
  '    at SingleNested.Document.$__init (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:694:3)\n' +
  '    at SingleNested.syncWrapper [as $__init] (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/kareem/index.js:331:25)\n' +
  '    at SingleNested.Document.init (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:638:8)\n' +
  '    at SingleNested.Document.$init (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:654:42)\n' +
  '    at SubdocumentPath.cast (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/SubdocumentPath.js:175:12)\n' +
  '    at _init (/usr/src/main-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:788:35)'
```

I don't understand why it fails validation when the new data I am trying to save.

### Current Models

**Domain.schema.ts**

```js
@Schema({ minimize: false })
export class Domain {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true,
    alias: 'id',
  })
  _id: string;
  id: string;

  /* nested ContactsObject */
  @Prop({ type: ContactsObjectSchema, default: {} })
  contacts: ContactsObject;
}

export const DomainsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Domain);
```

**Domain-sub.schema.ts**

```js
@Schema({ minimize: false })
export class ContactsObject extends Document {
  /* nested Contact types */
  @Prop({ type: ContactSchema })
  Registrant?: Contact;

  @Prop({ type: ContactSchema })
  Administrative?: Contact;

  /* ... there are more contact types */
}
export const ContactsObjectSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ContactsObjectObject);
export const ContactsModel = mongoose.model(ContactsObject.name, ContactsObjectSchema);

@Schema()
export class Contact extends Document {
  @Prop({ default: '' })
  name: string;

  /* ...lots more props... */
}
export const ContactSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Contact);
```

### Current (bad) data in Mongo

Querying the data in Mongo, I see the `contacts` is an `Array` and not a nested `Object`:

```js
{
  _id: 'asdf',
  contacts: [], // <-- this should be an empty Object {}
}
```

### Data trying to save

Right before I save the data, I call `model.toObject()` to inspect the data:

```js
// domainModel.toObject()
// outputs:
 {
  _id: 'asdf',
  contacts: {
    Registrant: {
      name: 'Company Name'
      /* ...etc */
    },
    Administrative: {/* ... */}
    // other expected sub fields
  }
 }
```

But calling `domainModel.save()` still throws that error above.

### What I have tried

1. I tried a `schema.pre('save')` and `schema.pre('validate')` hook and neither worked:

   ```js
   // also DomainsSchema.pre('validate', ...)
   DomainsSchema.pre('save', function () {
     if (Array.isArray(this?.contacts)) {
       this.contacts = new ContactsModel();
       // also tried plain object `{}`
     }
   });
   ```
2. I tried manually checking in my service before saving:

   ```js
     if (Array.isArray(domainModel?.contacts)) {
       domainModel.contacts = new ContactsModel();
     }
     await domainModel.save();
   ```

### Database Limitations

I thought about running a script on the MongoDB server to convert all of the "bad" data. However, I discovered that the legacy app has a bug where it will still create these "bad" records at random. I don't have the ability to fix the bug in the legacy app. I need to be able to code around it and correct it in my NestJS app.

### Versions

I am running a NestJS server with MongoDB & Mongoose. Here are my versions:

```
MongoDB server version: 4.4.20

node v18.12.0
npm@8.19.2

┬ mongoose@6.11.4
└── mongodb@4.16.0

@nestjs/mongoose@9.2.1
@nestjs/common@9.2.1
@nestjs/core@9.2.1
```

### Confusion / Question

I don't understand why/how Mongoose is validating against what is currently in the database, and not against the *new data* I am trying to save. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the time being, I added `domainModel.$markValid('contacts');` right before my `domainModel.save()` call. It is a little hacky and I don't like opt'ing out of validation like this – but it works for now.